# How can I update other component in React?

Tags: reactjs

There are react files A.js, B.js and C.js
And in A's render(), It calls <B/> <C/>
B shows the number.
In C, there is a button, and if click it, B's count will increase.

In this situation, How can I update B's count in C?
How can I pass the event to B in C?

Comment: Please provide code for more details

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will help you this time but this is something you can achieve just by reading the docs.

```
const A = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  <B count={count}/>
  <C onClick={() => setCount(count => count + 1)}/>
}

const B = ({count}) => <div>{count}</div>

const C = ({onClick}) => <button onClick={onClick}>Increase</button>
```

Comment: Should be: `<C onClick={()=>setCount(count => count + 1)}/>` but that would cause needless re renders in a real application.

Comment: Good catch, I edited my answer, and about the needless re-renders, check this article https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback

Comment: Thank you for the post, the cost of creating ten memoized functions is about the same as one needless re render. Especially when it comes to passing functions as props that are going to be used as handlers: `onClick={()=>'new function every render'}` this will not only fail quick virtual dom compare but fail deep compare and cause DOM updates (way more expensive than creating a memoized callback on mount). React team did not make these hooks because they were bored and had nothing better to do.

Answer (score 0):

I may need some more details. But from what it seems you need to keep the state of the number in component A. Pass the number state as a prop to component B, this way B will show whatever the current number is. For component C, create a function that can update the count in component A and pass that function to component C as a prop. In component C add the function for the onClick event on the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
//In A's Constructor:
this.state = {count: 0};

//In A's Class:
updateCount(){
   this.setState({count: this.state.count++});
}

In A's render:
<B count={this.state.count} />
<C onClick={this.updateCount} />
```

Use the prop `count` passed to B to display the count in B's render.

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use count state in A and define a function to increase count state. Pass count to B and the function to increase to C:

```js
const B = React.memo(function B({ count }) {
  return <div>in B, count is:{count}</div>;
});
const C = React.memo(function C({ increase }) {
  return <button onClick={increase}>+</button>;
});

function A() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const increase = React.useCallback(
    () => setCount((count) => count + 1),
    []
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <B count={count} />
      <C increase={increase} />
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<A />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried something. In function B: show the Count by doing this:

```
<div>
  {this.props.count}
</div>
```

where the count is passed in as a function. In function C, use `setState()` to increase the Count when class C is called.